# ssh can't connet to the puplic ip and can't connet to ssh acount

Tags: networking, ssh

Can anyone help me? When I try with my Internal IP but they don't work, When I try with my public IP, it gives me:

```
root@46.153.*******'s password: 
sshd listensocks[14]
Connection to 46.153.27.142 closed.
```

[image]

Comment: try ping the ip